# Vuetify Card Text Overflow - Multiline text ellipsis

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working with Vuetify cards.
As you can see in the picture below, the cards' height is variable until it reaches its **max-height** (I've set this value to 225px). I'd like to add a **text-overflow: ellipsis** once it surpasses the limit.

[image: Text overflow]

**Vuetify code**

```
<v-card rounded dark class="rounded-xl" max-height="225">
    <v-card-text class="elip">{{info.description}}</v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

**What I've tried**

```
.elip{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

A style class "elip" is added, and the end result is a one line card with ellipsis.
[image: One line card with ellipsis]

Comment: Does this help? [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: Not really, I've already tried that before. The end result is that it becomes a one line card...

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried. That might point out what is going wrong.

Comment: Try that with `overflow-y: hidden`.

Comment: It doesn't work either, it just adds a x - scrollbar. But it remains as a one line card

Comment: Multiline text with ellipsis is not a simple thing. Maybe have a read over here to achieve you goal with couple of CSS: https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-truncation-with-pure-css/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-webkit-line-clamp`, which allows limiting of the contents of a block container to the specified number of lines.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp)
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/raevilman/pen/OJpQXjg/left) for same. In this lorem ipsum text is truncated to 3 lines.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't marked as an answer. Me having concerns about browser compatability aside this totally works